# Can abstract factory be used for something other than creation

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have an abstract factory class that keeps a map of some types (application specific types as integers) and pointers to factory objects. This map is initialized in the constructor of the abstract factory which has a method called `IFactory* get_factory_for_type(int)`. `IFactory` is the interface which all factory classes must inherit from.

I also need a string representing of objects that each factory can produce and a list of all available object types.

If I add another map in the abstract factory (of type `std::map<int, std::string>`) and two methods `std::string get_name_for_type(int)` and `std::vector<std::string> get_type_names()`, will it be a good way to do it?

I am wary of doing it like this though as the abstract factory should only be responsible for creating object factories. Is there a better way to do it or is it okay to do this in the abstract factory?

Comment: `java`, `c#` and `c++` ?

Comment: It is a design pattern question, not language specific hence java, c# and c++.

Comment: I suggest moving this question to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of an abstract factory is the ability to create a specific set of objects, but adapted for a certain environment. The school book example is for windows/linux/mac etc, but a more relevant example would be for different persistence options.

As the types that the factory creates should be known, I don't see a reason to have some sort of enumeration of the objects as the objects should remain the same for all different environments.

That said, no one says that you have to follow patterns blindly. I would though recommend you to document the deviation and explain the purpose of it.

Answer (score 0):

Factory is for storing a collection and providing a way to get it. If you need something like getting details from an object, It's more of a translator rather than a factory, or you can create extension methods for it.

Details for translator: [Translator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949708/translator-pattern)